# Extra clean Wordpress clean urls

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm using wordpress for a site and I added an extra php page that uses a query string.

The url I currently have is site.com/page/**?query=stuff**

and I would like it to be site.com/page/**stuff**

I understand how to handle a .htaccess ReWrite rule for normal php projects but I'm having a hard time working around wordpresses .htaccess rules which are:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You could use the Wordpress rewrite API for that: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in any Wordpress install I've used it automatically identifies /search/query+terms the same as ?s=query+terms, so you really just need to redirect users to the more SEO version, in which case you just need to do the following:

Add the following just below `RewriteBase /`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1? [L,R=301]
```

So your final file will look like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Hope this helps!  If your Wordpress install doesn't identify /search/query+terms as a search then let me know and I'll see if I can help you further!  You can test this by manually going to the url before you try this, for example: example.com/search/hello+world

Comment: Also, if you are dealing with subdirectories (or your wordpress install is in a subdirectory) you might want to modify the second line I gave you to be this:
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1search/%1? [L,R=301]`